# ReactJS : Fetch response not returning to componentDidMount; Failed to load PDF

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

In ReactJS, component not re-rendering after receiving Fetch response. So always seeing "Loading PDF..." message in screen

componentDidMount code is given below,

```
    componentDidMount() {
        const {getData} = this.props;
        let data =  getData();
        console.log(data)      // printed empty while fetch in progress
        this.setState({pdfData : data})
        console.log(this.state.pdfData) // printed empty while fetch in progress
    }
```

After fetch, getData value (data) is not printed. pdfData is not set, due to this component is not re-rendering. At the same time, array value is printed in getData().

rendering returned data as pdf using react-pdf library

```
    render() {
        return(
            <div style={{ width: 500 }}>
            <Document
                file={this.state.pdfData }
                onLoadSuccess={() => console.log("Success")}
                onLoadError = {(error) => console.log(error.message)}
            >
                <Page pageNumber={1} />
            </Document>
            </div>
        );

    }
```

getData is given below,

```
export const getData = id => async (dispatch) => {
    let response;
    try {
        response = API_CALL
        console.log(response)                // PDF raw data printed
        let rawLength = response.length;
        let array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));
        for (let i=0; i < rawLength; i++){
            array[i] = response.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        console.log(array);                 //array value printed
        return array;
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(setError(error.message));
        throw error;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `getData` function is `async`, you will need to either `await` the result in  `componentDidMount` or act on the promise (assuming you are already `await`ing your API call). E.g.:

With await:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const { getData } = this.props;
    let data =  await getData(); // <-- Await the async here
    this.setState({ pdfData: data });
}
```

Or with the promise:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { getData } = this.props;
    getData().then((data) => { // <-- Act on the promise result
      this.setState({ pdfData: data });
    });
}
```

Comment: @user3362908 Happy to help! If this answer has solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark.